# How to adjust the frame of UITextView as per its content

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4.2

In my application I need to store the exact  area(height & width) within the textview that contains text.

I have a UITextView of width **300**. Now suppose the user wites some text which fills up to only **150** i.e **50%** of the width of the TextView.How can I know how much portion of the textview contains text?? I want to store only **150** not **300** i.e I need to exclude the redundant portion of textview that does not contain text.

However I have been able to get the exact height by using **textview.contentSize.height**.
But **textview.contentSize.width** does not give appropriate result

Any suggestions????

Answer (score 2):

You need to calculate the size of the text within the bounds of the UITextView:

```
CGSize textSize = [@"Some text" sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] forWidth:CGRectGetWidth(textView) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap];
```

From here here you can use the textSize.height property to set the height of your UITextView.

Please bear in mind you might have to tweak the font size and the `forWidth:` size to match whatever your UITextView has, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

This is coming straight from my working code:

```
//Make the textView as big as needed for it to fit the message body
CGSize stringSize = [m.msg_body sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:13]
                           constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 9999) 
                               lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

messageTextView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, stringSize.width, stringSize.height + 10);
```